# How to use cv2.videowriter to record the computer screen with the use of Tkinter and without displaying the screen while recording it (imgshow)

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, tkinter, opencv

What in reality I want to do is:

1. To use Tkinter buttons to:

   1.1. Start recording the screen

   1.2. Stop recording the screen
2. Not to display the video that is being recorded simultaneously during the recording.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('ScreenVideo')
window.geometry('350x300')

#ScreenVideo

def StartS():
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    vid=cv2.VideoWriter("c:\\IQOutput\\rec.avi", fourcc, 10, (990,690))

    while(True):
        img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(10,10,1000,700))
        img_np=np.array(img)
        frame=cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        vid.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
        key=cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key==27:
            break

    vid.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

bstarts = tk.Button(window, text='StartRe', font=('Arial', 8), bg='light pink', width=5, height=1, command=StartS)     
bstarts.place(x=280, y=80, anchor='nw')

bstops = tk.Button(window, text='StopRe', font=('Arial', 8), bg='light pink', width=5, height=1, command=StopRe)     
bstops.place(x=280, y=120, anchor='nw')
```

The piece of code above has the options below:

(a). Starts recording when the user clicks the Bstarts button.

(b). Shows the screen simultaneously while recording it within a "frame" window.

(c). Stops recording when the user presses the "esc" key on PC.

(d). Saves the final video (named: "rec.avi") in the path `C:\IQOutput\`.

But the options I expect this program to have are:

(a). When the user clicks the Bstarts button, it starts to record the screen (that is already working).

(b). Not to show the screen simultaneously while recording on the screen (how can I remove or hide the function related to "imshow" while the screen is being recorded?)

(c). When the user clicks the Bstops button, it stops recording the screen.

(d). It saves the final video named "rec.avi" in the path `c:\IQOutput\`.

Answer (score 0):

I answer the question (b) I asked:"(b). Not show screen video simultaneously in screen (how can I remove or hide function related to "imshow" during recording?)". my study is videowriter is must with imshow. so my workaround method is to resize and move the imshow window , the code is like:

```
    ....
    vid.write(frame)
    cv2.resizeWindow('frame', 20,20)
    cv2.moveWindow("frame", 5,5) 
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame) 
    ......
```

now the imshow window is small and on the top-left corner that will not interfere with I want to record.

However I still do not know how to use button of tkiinter to stop the record. the reason is (1)once I click bstarts button, this button function keep working on capture image frame to be video (2) so I can not use other button in "screenvideo" window before I press "esc" key to stop bstarts button function.

Comment: I find other way, I use python to call oCam (a very good screen shot and screen record application, can get good quality of picture and mp4 video), and use tkinter to press hotkeys of "start/stop screen recording" in Ocam, now it works good. Now I do not need to use cv2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion instead of while loop because when you are using while loop in tkinter they never release the button so there is no chances that you can stop looping.
But when you use recursion it is easy to stop looping by invoking other functions like stop button and you can change the after_id recursion to None.

```
def ScreenRe():
    global after_id
    global secs

    secs += 1
    if secs % 1 == 0:  # every other second
        img = pyautogui.screenshot()
        frame=np.array(img)
        frame=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        out.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow('show',frame)
    after_id = top.after(1000, ScreenRe)  # check again in 1 second

def start():
    global secs
    secs = 0
    ScreenRe()  # start repeated checking

def stop():
    global after_id
    if after_id:
        top.after_cancel(after_id)
        after_id = None
```